# How can I get domain name without WWW in C# or VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to get domain name without the "http" and "www".

For example:

```
 https://www.google.com => google.com

 http://www.google.com => google.com

 www.google.com => google.com
```

Attempts made:

```
               Dim myUri As New Uri(url)
                Dim host = myUri.Host
                Dim host1 = myUri.AbsolutePath
                Dim host2 = myUri.AbsoluteUri
                Dim host3 = myUri.Authority
                Dim host4 = myUri.DnsSafeHost
                Dim host5 = myUri.Fragment
                Dim host6 = myUri.HostNameType
```

None of this works for me. Can some one guide me how to achieve above in C# or VB.Net (preferrable VB.Net)

Comment: Do you want to exclude all sorts of subdomains (eg. codereview.stackexchange.com => stackexchange.com) or just www?

Comment: I want to get rid of just www

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest you can get is through the `Uri.Host` property. After that you need to use string manipulation like:

`myUri.Replace("www.", "")`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Won't work if the site is something like www.testwww.com or www3.test.com